# Получить значения (имя) индекса из Series по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть серия вида:

```
A       False
B       True
C       False
D       False
```

Как сделать список названий индексов, у которых значение `True` ?

Т.е. ожидаемы результат в данном случае: `['B',]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Индексы истинных элементов:

```
In [6]: s.loc[s].index
Out[6]: Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```

в виде Vanilla Python list:

```
In [9]: s.loc[s].index.to_list()
Out[9]: ['B']
```

---

Индексы ложных элементов:

```
In [7]: s.loc[s == False].index
Out[7]: Index(['A', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал такую реализацию, однако допускаю что есть что-то лучшее(в более пандасовском стиле)

*names* - серия из вопроса

```
[idx for idx in names.index if names[idx] == True]
```