# Получить все не числовые значения в нескольких столбцах

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125059/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-series-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E)
Пытаюсь создать что то вроде автотеста для данных из sql.
Как я могу отобрать все не числа в нескольких столбцах и получить их в виде нового DF?

По аналогии с данной функцией (возвращает все отсутствующие значения) -

```
def check_for_null(df): 
    """Проверка на отсутствующие значения всех столбцов""" 
    null_columns = df.columns[df.isnull().any()]
    df = (df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)][null_columns].head())
    return df
df_emptyRows = check_for_null(test_df)
```

У меня получилось разложить выбранные столбцы по маске True.False, и получить строки с False (это не числа). Не понятно как вернуть значения по индексам. Скорее всего не туда думаю.

```
 df = df[['zayavleno_st', 'nabrano_st','zayavleno_g','nabrano_g']].applymap(np.isreal).all(1)
 df2 = df.loc[df==False]
```

()[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выделенне значения - то, что я хочу получить назад.

Comment: Всегда нужно добавлять в вопрос пример исходных данных. ВСЕГДА.

Comment: в каком виде вы хотите получить строковые значения? приведите пример в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Вы в принципе думаете в верном направлении.
Единственная ремарка - ваши столбцы, имеющие строковые значения, всегда будут иметь тип `object`, то есть числа будут преобразовываться с строки. поэтому, имеет смысл проверять именно строки на то, может ли быть их содержимое числом

При исходных:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,"a",3,4], "b":[11,"b", 33, 44], "c":[111,"c", "cc", 444]})
```

```
   a   b    c
0  1  11  111
1  a   b    c
2  3  33   cc
3  4  44  444
```

сделать можно так, например:

```
res = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.isalpha())]
```

res:

```
     a    b    c
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    a    b    c
2  NaN  NaN   cc
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: _'числа будут преобразовываться с строки'_, но если сделать так `df.applymap(type)`, то видно, что в вашем примере числа имеют тип int

Comment: @SergFSM я рассматривал вариант с явным преобразованием типов, но, по-моему, это лишние движения, и, кроме того, нам не было точно сказано, какие еще типы данных могут быть в датафрейме.